# How to mock input and output for testing (for competitive programming)?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, patch

Let's say I have a function that prints an integer read from the console:

in submission.py:

```
def print_input():
    n = int(input())
    print(n)
```

How can I patch the input and output to test this function on an array of test cases?
(Obviously, I would like the mock methods for input/output to behave exactly like `input()` and `print()` in python.

Comment: There is [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). Another option is to write this as a function that takes input and output objects. Yet another is black box testing - have your tests run this as a subprocess and use its stdin and stdout for test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to give the return value from `input` and capture the `sys.stdout` from the print statement. e.g:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import io


def print_input():
    n = int(input())
    print(n)


class Test101(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_name(self):
        with mock.patch('sys.stdout', new=io.StringIO()) as fake_out:
            with mock.patch('builtins.input', return_value="1"):
                print_input()
                self.assertEqual("1\n", fake_out.getvalue())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: I've found that `with mock.patch('builtins.input', return_value="1"): user_input = function_that_gets_input()` is enough

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just define a new `input(...)` function on top of your code

```
def input():
    """
    monkey patch method that will override default
    """
    return 10

...

[your code here]
```